# Nativescript Javascript and Watson Cloud SDK Integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, nativescript, watson-conversation

So I am attempting to use the Watson `Assistant` module of the Watson Developer Cloud SDK.

I wish to use this lib in a Nativescript APP, with the end goal being I utilize the abilities of the library to take have a chat screen in the app, and take user data and send it to the bot, and vice versa.

Link: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk

I am trying to use the Node.js SDK, however upon installing I get the first error of `Buffer` not defined.

I have then gone through this guide, and installed Nodefiy

Link: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/how-to-use-any-npm-module-with-nativescript

I then placed `require(nativescript-Nodefiy)` within the `app.js` of the application, and within the `assistant.js` of the Watson NPM module.

This got rid of the `Buffer` error, however, continuing on, I then got "Stream module not found", then `https module not found`, and the list continues.

I then found this article on Kinvey Business logic:

Link: https://devcenter.kinvey.com/nativescript/reference/business-logic/reference.html#watson-module

The way they show it, shows that the `Watson-develop-cloud SDK` should just work with Nativescript.

I'm at a lose now what to do next, I would love to get it working, but knowledge resources are limited.

Any help and guidance would be awesome.

```
const HomeViewModel = require("./home-view-model");
require("nativescript-nodeify");
var AssistantV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/assistant/v2');


function onNavigatingTo(args) {
const page = args.object;
page.bindingContext = new HomeViewModel();
}

exports.onNavigatingTo = onNavigatingTo;
```

This is the only code I have in the "home-page.js" file, having just installed the "watson-developer-cloud" sdk, and then putting the "require('watson-develop-cloud...')" throws an error saying "Buffer" not defined

Comment: At least show us what you have done. I have implement a watson chatbot using this SDK and got no issue.

Comment: Would you like me to make a git, or just throw a snippet of code into my original question?

Comment: Just a snippet of code. But from your question, I assume that you want to run watson lib on your browser ?

Comment: Added a snippet. Oh? Maybe I'm using this wrong, can I not just utilize the abilities of the lib in my Nativescript app, and do what I please with the data? I.e: make calls to the cloud AI, and receive calls?

Comment: If you want to call API in browser, you will need to bundle their lib in server site using webpack or browsify. They have example here: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/tree/master/examples/webpack

For me, I develop a node server to use SDK and make an API in my server for browser to call.

Comment: Having everything in the browser also means that you have the credentials for Watson Assistant in the browser?! A typical use case is to make calls from the browser/client to the server which handles the calls to Watson Assistant.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you mention Kinvey in your question, however I do not know to what extend you are familiar with the platform.

[Progress® Kinvey™](https://www.progress.com/kinvey) is a serverless cloud backend platform for rapidly building enterprise mobile apps and experiences at consumer-scale. Developer productivity is dramatically accelerated using open source frontend frameworks integrated with a low-code backend that enable out of the box integrations with enterprise and legacy systems. You can easily deliver multi-channel externally facing apps faster without worrying about infrastructure, platform and DevOps.

Kinvey offers variety of SDKs using which you can build native, hybrid, web and IoT apps. Indeed one of the SDKs that Kinvey offers is for NativeScript. Please save this [link](https://devcenter.kinvey.com/nativescript/), as it is the official DevCenter documentation for Kinvey's NativeScript SDK.

Continuing on your post, I see that you've read about the Kinvey Business Logic feature. It is a NodeJS code execution runtime that allows you to customize the behavior of requests to your backend by providing a means to implement server-side business logic. Kinvey Business Logic enables developers to focus on the unique functional business logic of a mobile application, while Kinvey handles the work of receiving, parsing, and routing requests, connecting to and querying data stores, and enabling mobile-specific functionality. Please refer to this [link](https://devcenter.kinvey.com/nativescript/guides/business-logic) to get more information about the core-concepts of Kinvey Business Logic.

One of the greatest benefits of using Kinvey Business Logic is that you have access to a series of API modules that can be used to manipulate or action on a request. To your information, one of those modules is called *[IBM Watson](https://devcenter.kinvey.com/nativescript/reference/business-logic/reference.html#watson-module)*. The *IBM Watson* module provides support for integrating with the IBM Watson APIs. This library exposes the "watson-developer-cloud" library.

Please feel free to go through the information that I've shared above, and familiarize yourself with Kinvey. Feel free to also join [Kinvey's Customer Support portal](https://support.kinvey.com/support/home).

I hope, I have informed you well.